# How to make a read-only property in Rhapsody

Tags: properties, rhapsody

When I load as reference an external profile to my Rhapsody project I'm not able to modify its properties as it is a reference.

Is there any way to make some properties (not all) read-only at project level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make them all read-only if you maintain your profile in a separate model and load that in the models you need.

I don't think you can protect single properties.